# Trying to override a global virtual method and receiving @Override specified for non-overriding method

Tags: apex

I have a global class which is part of a managed package.  The methods in the managed class are all global virtual.  In the global class I have 2 methods;

```
global virtual Decimal calculateCompensationEligibleMargin(Load__c load){
        return calculateCompensationEligibleMargin(load, false);
}
global virtual Decimal calculateCompensationEligibleMargin(Load__c load, Boolean IsEstimateRun){
...
}
```

I can extend the global class (no problem) and I can override the method `calculateCompensationEligibleMargin(Load__c load)`

But when I try to override the second method  `calculateCompensationEligibleMargin(Load__c load, Boolean IsEstimateRun)` I receive the error "@Override specified for non-overriding method ..."

Comment: Without seeing the specific code used, I can only presume there's a typo, or you used the wrong return type (which must also match the method).

Comment: I've checked the spelling it's all correct.  I have extended this class in the past and over ridden other methods without any issues but this is the first time that I have tried to over ride this method.  I can override the method that takes a single parameter but not the method of the same name that takes two parameters.

Comment: Please edit to show the extending class's declaration and the overriding method's full signature.

Comment: Check that you really are passing a `Load__c` and a `Boolean` to the method.

Comment: As I was getting ready to respond with the class declaration I deployed the class to the sandbox just for old time sake and it worked?  This was not a 'I made a change that I'm not sharing that fixed this issue'  all I did was deployed the class again and 16 hours later it worked?  This wasn't a visual studio issue either because I tried making the changes yesterday in the sandbox directly and I received the same error?  Thanks to everyone who responded.